# How could an elf PC disguise themselves as a human?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, disguise

I am going to be playing in a Castlevania-based D&D 5e game. In this world there is strong racism against elves and a general fear of magic. I want to be an elf, but I think in this world I would be inclined to try and hide that fact from my party and anyone I met. Do you have any suggestions for how to go about this before I bring it up to my DM?

Comment: What is your class and starting level?

Comment: Very much related: [Could a lvl 1 drow disguise their race from party for lengthy period of time?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50815/could-a-lvl-1-drow-disguise-their-race-from-party-for-lengthy-period-of-time?rq=1)

Comment: You also need to think about what happens when the party finds out your character is an elf. What are their reactions going to be when they discover a trusted travelling companion has been lying to them? What are you going to when a player says "My character doesn't trust your character anymore and wishes them to leave the group."?

Comment: I haven't quite decided. I was thinking a ranger to fit into my party, they have a bard warrior, rogue, and a paladin. There is a half elf in my party as well. Our first game is soon we are starting at 1st levels. I'm still brainstorming and deciding if it will be worthwhile or more of a distraction.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Qt1cF93u-6A?t=45

Comment: I recommend you to read this: http://theangrygm.com/angry-rants-secrets-part-2/. It is a text about backstory secrets, and how to best tackle them. If you read this, and follow the writer's advice, it could save you from a lot of pain at the table. It is a part 2, part one is about plot-secrets, and is more directed towards GMs. You can read the second part without reading the first.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest thing to do, that is accessible to any character, and requires very little investment of resources, is to get proficiency in the disguise kit (probably from your background).

> ***Disguise Kit.***
>   This pouch of cosmetics, hair dye, and
>   small props lets you create disguises that change your
>   physical appearance. Proficiency with this kit lets you
>   add your proficiency bonus to any ability checks you
>   make to create a visual disguise.

All you *really* need to do is hide your ears, and "disguises that change your
physical appearance" sounds like it should certainly be able to do that. This is almost certainly the best option, but here are some others.

The 1st-level *disguise self* spell will allow you to disguise yourself as a human, and anyone can get it with the Magic Initiate feat. However, it only lasts 1 hour, so you'll probably need to be able to cast it multiple times per day.

If you can talk your DM into giving you one (good luck!) a Hat of Disguise lets you cast *disguise self* at will.

The 2nd-level *alter self* spell will also allow you to disguise yourself as a human, but will require you to be a third-level wizard or sorcerer. It also requires concentration, so there's a risk of your disguise dropping at an unfortunate moment.

As mentioned in [another answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72055/15469), a 2nd-level warlock has access to an invocation that allows them to cast *disguise self* at will, which would be great for you. A 15th-level warlock has access to an invocation which allows them to cast *alter self* at will, but that's not really an option unless your campaign starts at a high level and you were planning to be a warlock anyway.

A 14th-level druid of the Circle of the Moon can also cast *alter self* at will, and it's likewise infeasible except if you're starting at high level and planning on becoming a druid anyway.

Comment: Regrettably don't have the PHB in front of me: does Alter Self also require Concentration?

Comment: Recommend referencing that. Getting smacked while shifted, or having to concentrate on another thing, will worsen the view of Alter Self.

Comment: Any druid in a Castlevania game who *doesn't* take Circle of the Moon is dangerously genre-ignorant.

Comment: Wouldn't Magic Initiate require at a minimum level 4 and a DM who is using the variant rule that allows feats?

Answer (score 4):

I played a warlock with the Mask of Many Faces invocation that allows one to cast disguise self at will in order to hide my race. It was quite effective, but did require 2nd level. He also had the actor feat, which further aids impersonation.

Comment: Invocation: Mask of Many Faces.
Actor: +1 Charisma, Advantage on Deception/ Performance with regard to pretending to be a person, ability to 'learn' a voice after X minute(s) of listening.

Answer (score 2):

Ear surgery aside, a magic item that disguises your character (both visually and covering any accent in speech) seems the most likely way -- plus giving the DM some hooks to hang adventures on (someone recognizes the disguise item, detects the magic, etc. and blackmails or threatens your elf, or asks for help only an elf could give; your infravision/dark vision gives you away, someone wonders why you're so slender and asks just the wrong questions -- the fun goes on and on).

Comment: I actually had a half elf character who literally cut the tips of their ears off in a game as part of his backstory!